# scan available wireless networks every 5 second java android

Tags: java, android, wifi, network-scan

I Want To Check For Available Wireless Networks Every 5 Second In My Phone.

so i write This code for my app but this code check WIFI Networks every 15 second !

This Is a service , that scan WIFI Networks every 15 second and if founds a without password WIFI vibrates the phone an play a sound...

How Can I Check Wireless Networks every 5 or 3 seconds ?

```
package com.sirbl4ck.wififinder;

import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MyService extends Service {
    WifiManager mainWifiObj;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    PowerManager pm;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

    public MyService() {
    }
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {        
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"Log");
        wl.acquire();
        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        mainWifiObj.startScan();
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        Toast.makeText(this, "WIFI Finder Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        wl.release();
        Toast.makeText(this, "WIFI Finder Service Stoped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void alert(){
        final MediaPlayer als = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alertm);
        als.start();
    }
    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
           List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
           for(int iss=0;iss<wifiScanList.size();iss++){
             String uug=wifiScanList.get(iss).toString();
             if(uug.contains("WPA") && !uug.contains("WEP")){
                 v.vibrate(1500);
                 alert();
                 Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "WIFI Found !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
           }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry For Language ...  I don't Understand English Well :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try use a recursive Thread:

```
public void startScan(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainWifiObj.startScan();
            startScan();
        }
    }, 5*1000);
}
```

Comment: I want to add an offer to this answer.
Just to stop phone from periodically wasting resources you can do next.
Every next time myltiply delay on some value. For example 2.
So you will scan for networks in: 5, 10, 20, 40 seconds.

And according to your application logic sometimes drop this value to 1, to scan with beginning values.

Comment: @maffelbaffel, please can your above code operates every one second? I tried to use it , it's working only in case of 5 second, if we use less than 5 second (e.x., 1 sec) , the (wifiScanList) return null, until the elapsed time become 5 sec and then we get the  wifiScanList values.  Could you explain why this happens?